# Get the table headers of the cells having quantities and display in bill using google sheet formula

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a google spreadsheet where I need to fetch the quantities and ordered fruits from the releavnt customer. The headers are expected to be fetched and placed in (yellow cells) based on the bill number(red color cell) choosen.

I have tried with vlookup for fetching the amount and finding total price which works great.

The below screenshot is

For example the bill number 5 is choosen, Matt will be displayed in the bill and using vlookup, and display Apple Banana and Mango to be displayed based on formula

When bill number 2 is choosen Cathy will be displayed and in yellow cells only Banana and Mango will be displayed (apple and pineapple should not be displayed as Cathy didnt purchase them)

Here is the Google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n2XgoUHZh9GwWGTQP8nvK2MV3uoXzP7s9V7aXLMbOrk/edit#gid=1150750443

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(TRIM(
 IF((A2:A7=B11)*(D2:G7<>""),D1:G1&" ♦ ♠ ♦"&D2:G7, ))), 
 "where Col1 is not null"), "♦♠")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Can you explain me ♦♠ these characters?

Comment: those are just unique characters or "splitters"... you split the string at them to remove them so you are left with just your original data